# How to simulate Home Key pressing in Qt/Android from QML?

Tags: android, qt, qml

All I want is to pretend that the Home Key was pressed instead the Back Key:

`Keys.onReleased:
        {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Back)
            {
                // Here I just wanna act like the home key was pressed
            }
        }`

How to do that in QML?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Is there some other approach to this?

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 startActivity(i);
```